# DC Motor with Rosserial help

Tags: ros, arduino, driver, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to make a controllable arduino robot. Is there anyone out there who knows how to make a motor turn without a motor shield (Is a motor shield really necessary)? Also, I am getting encoders for the DFRobot 4WD robot

[DFRobot 4WD Arduino-Compatible Platform w / Encoders](http://www.robotshop.com/productinfo.aspx?pc=RB-Dfr-67&lang=en-US)

and wanted to write a ROS driver for it. I have an xbee radio I'd like to put to use with it too. I have never written a driver, so, for those with experience, help would be great! And tips, tutorials, or general advice welcome!

thanks,

-Hunter A.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30417/dc-motor-with-rosserial-help/) by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3055 on 2012-03-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Go to my site:

https://www.sites.google.com/site/shridharshah/projects/ros-arduino-xbee

I have done exactly what you need. I have provided full documentation. Let me know if any questions.

---

Originally posted by [sks](https://answers.ros.org/users/2910/sks/) with karma: 36 on 2012-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hamzh.albar@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/36205/hamzh.albar@gmail.com/) on 2018-07-19**:
Hello @sks , I have questions for you, let me know if you are willing to answer them.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, you need some motor controller, you can buy a variety of them or build your own H-Bridge. Suggest you google how to build a simple robot, there are lots of examples. Also look on the Arduino website for examples of how to do this too. Start simple and work your way up to ROS.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-03-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is a link that helped me a lot i his latest ros driver is more for the maple
but the rest is very good
[link text](http://www.hessmer.org/blog/)

---

Originally posted by [Peter Heim](https://answers.ros.org/users/71/peter-heim/) with karma: 215 on 2012-03-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4